# Proof in Group Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that if $G$ is a finite group with identity $e$ and with an even number of elements, then there is an $a \neq e$ in $G$, such that $a \cdot a = e$.

I read the solutions here http://noether.uoregon.edu/~tingey/fall02/444/hw2.pdf

Why do they say $D = \{a, a^\prime\}$? Isn't $D$ not a group? There is no identity and if they include the identity they get 3 elements, which means $|D| = 3 = $ odd.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the relation on $G$ given by $g\equiv h\iff g\in\{\ h\ , h^{-1}\ \}$. It is easy to see that this is symmetric, reflexive, and transitive, and so an equivalence relation with equivalence classes $\{\ h\ ,\ h^{-1}\ \}$. The equivalence class of the identity $e$ of $G$ is $\{\ e\ \}$ containing only one element, and all equivalence classes have at most two elements. Since the order of $G$ is even, at least one equivalence class besides $\{\ e\ \}$ must have only one element, and that element is its own inverse.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that $D$ is not a subgroup of $G$, but they don't claim that it is.

They're also not saying that $D = \{a, a^{-1}\}$, but rather that the elements of $D$ appear in pairs -- if $a \in S$, then $(a^{-1})^2 = a^{-2} = (a^2)^{-1} \neq e$.

Go back through the proof and see if it makes sense now.

Comment: But then how can D have odd elements if all elements come in pairs plus the identity? You will get 2k + 1 elements

Comment: I'm assuming you mean "even," not "odd."

Is $e$ in $D$, or in $S$?

Comment: Yes I meant to say how can D have even elements. e is in S not D. I get the gist of the proof now. Why would D and S be disjoint though? isn't $a$ in the intersection?

Comment: @sizz I think the notation is confusing you. $S$ is the set of all elements of $G$ whose square is the identity. $D$ is the set of all elements of $G$ whose square isn't the identity. Stated this way (without mentioning $a$), you can see that $S$ and $D$ are disjoint. The $a$ just gives a way of writing the condition symbolically ($a*a=e$) within the definition of $S$ (or $D$), instead of saying it in words as "whose square is (or isn't) the identity." The $a$ has no meaning outside the definition itself, so saying "$a$ is in the intersection" is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

let $e,a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ be the elements of the group since the number of these elements is even we get the number of these elemnts  $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ is odd, now start putting every element with its inverse in a set lets say $\{a_i,a_j\}$ since the number is odd you will be left with one element call it $a$ and you have $a.a=e$.